# convert tensorflow array stored as string to a file back to tensorflow. Examples and details

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

```
tf.Tensor(\n[[[0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  ...\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]]\n\n [[0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  ...\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]]\n\n [[0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  ...\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]]\n\n ...\n\n [[0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  ...\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]]\n\n [[0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  ...\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]]\n\n [[0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  ...\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]\n  [0 0 0]]], shape=(96, 96, 3), dtype=uint8)
```

The above example is a real example. I need to convert it to tensorflow format again.

Answer (score 0):

try tensorflow.io.decode_raw
e.g. for byte string to tensor with uint8's:

```
import tensorflow as tf
oldthing = originaluint8array.tobytes() # looks like a numpy array in my original code
newthing = tf.io.decode_raw(oldthing, tf.uint8)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).